# How can I remove the hover effect from my tags?

Tags: css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm currently using this tumblr theme and I'm hopeless with code. I've been trying to do it on my own with no avail.

I want to take away the hover effects on the tags, as well as change the color to a darker grey so it's not so hard to view.

I'd also like to be able to see my tags at all times, rather than only when clicking on the posts.

How would I go about doing that?

pastebin(.)com/hcGEQDM6

Comment: can you share us your code? so we can help you out regarding your problem

Comment: it's linked here!: https://pastebin.com/hcGEQDM6

Comment: Nope, code belongs in the question, so future users that have a similar issue can refer to it.  See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to get rid of the hover effect on all of you tags you should remove the style of your page that has `:hover`  on your CSS.

## Codes with `:hover`:

```
   a:hover {
      color:{color:hover};
    } 
    
    #sidebar:hover #sidebarimage img{
        border-radius:0px;
        margin-left:-100px;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
    
    #sidebar:hover .desc{
        margin-top:-2px;
        opacity:1;
        -moz-transition-duration:1s;
        -webkit-transition-duration:1s; 
        -o-transition-duration:1s;  
    } 
    
    .links a:hover {     
        text-align:center;
        color:{color:sblink};
        background:white;
        -moz-transition-duration:0.9s;
        -webkit-transition-duration:0.9s;
        -o-transition-duration:0.9s;
         text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    #sidebar:hover .links{
        margin-left:54px;
        opacity:1;
        -moz-transition-duration:0.9s;
        -webkit-transition-duration:0.9s;
        -o-transition-duration:0.9s;
    } 

 
#pagi a:hover{
    color:{color:hover};}

#info a:hover {
    text-align:center; 
    color:{color:hover} ;
    -moz-transition-duration:.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.8s;
    -o-transition-duration:.8s; 

    }

#tags a:hover {    
    -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.5s;
    color:{color:Hover};
    }

.audiop:hover{
    -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.5s;
}
#postnotes li:hover {
    color:{color:hover};

}

#postnotes li:hover a {
    color:{color:hover};
}

#credit a:hover { color: {color:linkhover};}
```